# Specific Row protection with specific Cell Value in Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-protection

I have data with various Name & email, Now I want to share the google spreadsheet to everyone whose name and email in google sheet but **Specific** Gmail id person should edit that Row only so how I can protect With general formula or macros

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible (using GAS maybe?) but one thing you can do is make THEM create a spreadsheet and then you can use IMPORTRANGE formula to import their inputs and consolidate the data into one master SS.

Comment: But I want them to edit in row

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.